grepl with thousands of patterns in R
I'm trying to find row matches with grepl. Grepl in this case is important because I'm also trying to find partial matches. The problem is that I have thousands of patterns
I was using this:
matches = mypattern_list$names

df2 = df %>% filter(grepl(paste(matches, collapse = "|"), target_column))

But because I have thousands of patterns, I get the following error:
TRE pattern compilation error 'Out of memory'

Is there anyway of doing the same, with grepl, but using reduce and lapply for example?
Example dataframe (small version)
mypattern_list= read.table(text="Names
fox
turtle
shark
etc_up_to_10000", sep="\t", header=TRUE)

df= read.table(text="target column
The (fox) was running into the forest
This phrase has nothing to do with animals
baby SHARK
etc_up_to_10000", sep="\t", header=TRUE)

Where the result would be anything that contains the key words:
results= read.table(text="results
The (fox) was running into the forest
baby SHARK
etc_up_to_10000", sep="\t", header=TRUE)

Minimal reproducible example:
res <- grepl(paste(1:10000, collapse = "|"), 1:10000)


You could try libraries that don't use TRE, e.g. stringi or ore, but given you're hitting a memory limit I doubt you'll have massively different results. Can you run grepl(paste(matches, collapse = "|"), x), where x is a character vector of length one? If so, find the maximum length you can run it on, split the data frame into chunks of that size, apply the matches then combine back into one data frame.

This runs instantly for me even though it has 1000 patterns and a 1000 length data vector:: res <- grepl(paste(1:1000, collapse = "|"), 1:1000)  Please provide a minimal reproducible example that does not work for you.

Workaround: break your patterns into several groups and make "OR statement" with grepls

As well as what has already been suggested, I feel a list of "texts that I'm interested in" is a little crude.  Can you proprocess your match list to reduce the number of items?  For example, rather than looking for "[tree|three]", try "[th*ree]".  My regex isuntested, but you get the idea....

I'm not sure how I can make a reproducible example out of my giant list of random words! I have 20000 rows in one dataframe (with text in each row), and over 13000 key words on my matches. I also have 64gb so i think this is a problem of being more efficient with the code. I will think of a way to try to make a reproducible example. I can't preprocess any of the lists because they have "named" keywords.

Then make a reproducible example out of a subset of your data.  There's plenty of advice on how to create a MRE on SO.  " can't preprocess any of the lists because they have "named" keywords." I'm not dure how that follows.  Perhaps a MRE would explain.

How big are your individual patterns? How long are the text strings? Are the individual patterns simple exact matches, or are other regex capabilities like quantifiers and special characters used?

@G.Grothendieck et al, OP's MRE does reproduce the error for me. grepl(paste(1:10000, collapse = "|"), 1:10000) gives Error in grepl... invalid regular expression '1|2|3|4|5|6|7... and In addition: Warning message: TRE pattern compilation error 'Out of memory'. I tried with PCRE = TRUE and got the same error with warning PCRE pattern compilation error 'regular expression is too large' at ''. This is with R 4.4.0 with Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.5 with 16Gb of memory. Code works fine if I use 1:100 instead of 1:10000.

MRE reproduces for me too with with 4.4.1 under Ubuntu 24.04 . Many of the answers here would work if inverted ...

The individual patterns are strings from 4 to 30 characters, including dots. The text strings are from 10 to 200 characters, containing simple text with parentheses, commas and dots. It works fine with grepl for up to a 1000 matches, without preprocessing

@GregorThomas grepl(paste(1:10000, collapse = "|"), 1:10000) reproduces the error for me too, but but stringi::stri_detect(1:10000, regex = paste(1:10000, collapse = "|")) runs without a problem...

Several of the answers from here can be adapted to this, I think:
grepl_any <- function(value, targets, ...) {
   all_matches <- sapply(targets, \(t) grepl(t, value, ...))
   apply(all_matches, 1, any)
}
dplyr::filter(df, grepl_any(target.column, mypattern_list$Names,
                            ignore.case = TRUE))

You might be able to squeeze out a little bit more efficiency by batching the targets and paste/collapsing each batch ...)
I haven't bothered simulating a 'big' MRE similar to your stated constraints, but you could try it and see if it's fast enough ...

I'd add that, if the individual patterns are exact matches and ignore.case isn't needed, then adding fixed = TRUE could speed this up quite a bit.

if the individual patterns are exact matches, I can do something like df[df$target %in% matches,] which works for hundreds of thousands of matches! I agree with fixed=TRUE but not sure how both methods compare

@GabrielG. terminology is hard here. %in% works for an exact match of the whole string: 'a' %in% 'a' is obviously TRUE, but 'a' %in% 'ab' is not. The grepl argument fixed = TRUE means you're not using regular expressions, but you are still matching substrings: grepl(pattern = 'a', x = 'ab', fixed = TRUE) will return TRUE but be much faster than grepl(pattern = 'a', x = 'ab'). But when you use fixed = TRUE you can't use regex special characters for their special meaning, | will not mean "OR", it will match a literal | in the string.

So fixed = TRUE won't work at all if you collapse all your patterns together with | as a separator, but Ben's answer here tests that patterns one-at-a-time, so fixed = TRUE will speed it up significantly.

(I re-ran GKi's benchmark and with fixed = TRUE and it's about 2 to 3 times faster, but with longer patterns and input the efficiency gains may increase.)

I see! Glad to learn something new

An approach using data.table and like. The sort can be omitted if the order of matches doesn't matter (in case of multiple matches).
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[sort(unlist(lapply(seq_along(mypattern_list$Names), \(x) 
  which(like(target.column, mypattern_list$Names[x], ignore.case=T)))))]
                           target.column
                                  <char>
1: The (fox) was running into the forest
2:                            baby SHARK
3:                       etc_up_to_10000

Note that like is a (somtimes faster) wrapper around grepl

I don't see why like should be any faster than grepl, except in the case of factors. It is just a wrapper: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/like.R

Yes, it can be replaced with grepl in most approaches.

If the pattern is to long for the build in grepl and throws an Out of memory you can try to use perl=TRUE, stringi::stri_detect, ore::ore_ismatch or split the regex in smaller pieces. Using stringi or ore will be faster than a loop to compare each single element.
x <- c("a", "c")
y <- c("a", "b", "c")

grepl(paste(x,  collapse = "|"), y)  # will throw 'Out of memory' for long patterns
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

grepl(paste(x,  collapse = "|"), y, perl=TRUE)  # will throw 'regular expression is too large' for long patterns
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

Reduce(\(a,b) a | grepl(b, y), x, FALSE)  # Will take very long time for long patterns
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

Reduce(\(a,b) `[<-`(a, !a, grepl(b, y[!a])), x, logical(length(y)))  # Search only in those which don't have already a match
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

Reduce(\(a,b) a | grepl(b, y, perl=TRUE),
  lapply(split(x, gl(ceiling(length(x)/1000), 1000, length(x))), paste, collapse="|"),
  FALSE)  # Make smaller groups
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

Reduce(\(a,b) `[<-`(a, !a, grepl(b, y[!a], perl=TRUE)),
 lapply(split(x, gl(ceiling(length(x)/1000), 1000, length(x))), paste, collapse="|"),
 logical(length(y)))  # Smaller groups and subset
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

stringi::stri_detect(y, regex = paste(x,  collapse = "|"))  # Thanks to @SamR for the comment
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

ore::ore_ismatch(paste(x,  collapse = "|"), y)  # Thanks to @SamR for the comment
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE


Benchmark
grepl_any <- function(value, targets, ...) { # @Ben Bolker
   all_matches <- sapply(targets, \(t) grepl(t, value, ...))
   apply(all_matches, 1, any)
}

M <- alist(
  grepl = grepl(paste(x,  collapse = "|"), y),
  greplPerl = grepl(paste(x,  collapse = "|"), y, perl=TRUE),
  grepl_any = grepl_any(y, x),
  Reduce = Reduce(\(a,b) a | grepl(b, y), x, FALSE),
  ReduceFixed = Reduce(\(a,b) a | grepl(b, y, fixed=TRUE), x, FALSE),
  ReduceSubset = Reduce(\(a,b) `[<-`(a, !a, grepl(b, y[!a], fixed=TRUE)), x, logical(length(y))),
  stringi = stringi::stri_detect(y, regex = paste(x,  collapse = "|")),
  ore = ore::ore_ismatch(paste(x,  collapse = "|"), y),
  subGrp = Reduce(\(a,b) a | grepl(b, y, perl=TRUE), lapply(split(x, gl(ceiling(length(x)/1000), 1000, length(x))), paste, collapse="|"), FALSE),
  subGrpSu = Reduce(\(a,b) `[<-`(a, !a, grepl(b, y[!a], perl=TRUE)), lapply(split(x, gl(ceiling(length(x)/1000), 1000, length(x))), paste, collapse="|"), logical(length(y)))
)

set.seed(42)
n <- 1000
x <- as.character((n/5+1):(n*1.2))
y <- paste0("a", sample(x), "z")
x <- sample(x, n/2)
bench::mark(exprs = M)

#   expression        min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#   <bch:expr>   <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1 grepl         11.82ms  12.34ms      80.9   11.86KB     0       41     0
# 2 greplPerl      5.07ms    5.2ms     187.     7.91KB     0       94     0
# 3 grepl_any      42.7ms  44.31ms      22.4   13.56MB     2.24    10     1
# 4 Reduce        38.62ms  38.76ms      25.7    3.87MB     0       13     0
# 5 ReduceFixed   10.73ms  11.25ms      84.9    3.87MB     2.07    41     1
# 6 ReduceSubset  13.76ms   14.4ms      67.8   16.92MB     7.01    29     3
# 7 stringi        5.09ms   5.36ms     188.    10.01KB     0       94     0
# 8 ore             7.6ms   7.84ms     126.     1.64MB     2.10    60     1
# 9 subGrp         5.07ms   5.42ms     181.    21.77KB     0       91     0
#10 subGrpSu       5.02ms   5.29ms     187.    57.31KB     0       94     0

set.seed(42)
n <- 10000
x <- as.character((n/5+1):(n*1.2))
y <- paste0("a", sample(x), "z")
x <- sample(x, n/2)
bench::mark(exprs = M[-1])  # Method 1 throws 'Out of memory'

#  expression        min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr>   <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 greplPerl    521.33ms 521.33ms     1.92   142.74KB    0         1     0
#2 grepl_any       4.99s    4.99s     0.200    1.31GB    0.601     1     3
#3 Reduce          4.38s    4.38s     0.228  381.93MB    0.228     1     1
#4 ReduceFixed     1.41s    1.41s     0.709  381.93MB    0.709     1     1
#5 ReduceSubset    1.43s    1.43s     0.700    1.63GB    2.80      1     4
#6 stringi      524.91ms 524.91ms     1.91   103.63KB    0         1     0
#7 ore          715.89ms 715.89ms     1.40    16.45MB    0         1     0
#8 subGrp       738.36ms 738.36ms     1.35   534.46KB    0         1     0
#9 subGrpSu     582.17ms 582.17ms     1.72     1.87MB    0         1     0

set.seed(42)
n <- 100000
x <- as.character((n/5+1):(n*1.2))
y <- paste0("a", sample(x), "z")
x <- sample(x, n/2)
bench::mark(exprs = M[c(-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6)])  # Method 1 throws Out of memory, Method 2 'regular expression is too large', Method 3 uses in my case to much total memory, Method 4, 5 and 6 use more than 1 hour

#  expression      min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
#1 stringi      51.82s 51.82s    0.0193    1.15MB   0          1     0     51.82s
#2 ore           1.54m  1.54m    0.0108  164.27MB   0.0540     1     5      1.54m
#3 subGrp        1.42m  1.42m    0.0117   39.61MB   0          1     0      1.42m
#4 subGrpSu      1.02m  1.02m    0.0164  168.93MB   0.0655     1     4      1.02m

